# VLC for HLS: getting ts file index numbers to wrap around

Tags: vlc

I am using VLC for HTTP live streaming as explained in [Graffen's blog](http://blog.graffen.dk/post/Publishing-video-content-to-your-iPhone-using-HTTP-Live-Streaming-with-VLC). Everything is working as expected. But I want to make the index number for ts files to wrap around after a certain count. For eg. I set "dst=c:/inetpub/wwwroot/live/mystream-########.ts". Then files with name mystream-00000001.ts, mystream-00000002.ts etc are produced with an always incrementing index file numbers. I want to make these index numbers to wrap around after a certain count, say after 10 files. So VLC will produce files from mystream-00000001.ts to mystream-00000010.ts and then again mystream-00000001.ts after mystream-00000010.ts instead of mystream-00000011.ts. What VLC command line setting can I use to make the ts file index number to wrap around?

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your question right, but wouldn't

```
"dst=c:/inetpub/wwwroot/live/mystream-#.ts"
```

wrap around at exactly 10 files? And

```
"dst=c:/inetpub/wwwroot/live/mystream-##.ts"
```

at 100.

Or you need an arbitrary number, not just powers of 10?